# Having trouble with 2 combinatorics problem.

Tags: combinatorics

- If $a+b+c+d+e=20$ and $a+b=15$ when, $a,b,c,d,e\ge0$  and they are integers, 
  what is the number of valid values of $a,b,c,d,e$ ?

  Here,
  $$a+b=15\ \ \ \ ....(1)$$
  $$c+d+e=5\ \ \ \ ....(2)$$
  From equation *(1)*, the number of values of $a,b=$ ${16 \choose 1}$

  and from equation *(2)*, the number of values of $c,d,e=$ ${7 \choose 2}$

  So, the number of total values is  ${16 \choose 1}+{7 \choose 2}$

  Is my solution correct?
- How many nonnegative integer solutions equation $3x+y+z=24$ have?

  I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: For the number of total values in the first question, $\times$, not $+$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question you need to consider $${16 \choose 1}\times {7 \choose 2}=336$$

instead of $${16 \choose 1}+{7 \choose 2}$$ because for each case of $a+b=15$ you have ${7 \choose 2}$ cases of $c+d+e=5$

For the second question, you notice that your equation is the same as $$y+z=3(8-x)$$

Thus $x$ can take on the $9$ possible values of $\{0,1,2,...,8\}$ and for each of these values you have $$y+z=3(8-x)$$

You will get a total of $$1+4+7+...+25=117$$ solutions.